# Continuation from a list element

Tags: python

I have a list and I want to continue from a particular list element which is a string

Example

```
a = ['Sam','Julian','Edna','Jack','Tressa']

for name in a['Julian':]:
  print(name)
```

But doing so gives me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    for name in a['Julian':]:
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

How do I address this to achieve the same outcome, when my actual list consists of thousands of such strings?

Comment: Couldn't you locate the index of the string and then use that?

Comment: use `for name in a:` if you want all names to be printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
for name in a[a.index('Julian'):]:
```

[`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) returns the index where the element in question was first seen, raising `ValueError` if it's not found.

An alternative solution that works for arbitrary iterables (and only requires a single pass) would be to use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to drop elements until you reach the desired one:

```
for name in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x != 'Julian', a):
```

That will iterate `a`, throwing away all values until a value is equal to `'Julian'`, then it will yield *all* subsequent values (whether or not they're equal to `'Julian'`). The advantage is that it only needs to perform a single pass of the data, where `for name in a[a.index('Julian'):]:` is doing roughly two passes in the worst case scenario; a partial pass to find the first instance of `'Julian'`, and partial pass of the rest of the `list` to slice it, then a third pass to actually iterate over the resulting slice.

Answer (score 2):

You can only select this way if you use an integer value corresponding to the **index** as a starting point.So you can use `a.index('Julian')` to get the index of `'Julian'`

```
Julian=a.index('Julian')
print(Julian)

1
```

---

```
a = ['Sam','Julian','Edna','Jack','Tressa']

for name in a[Julian:]:
    print(name)

Julian
Edna
Jack
Tressa
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot index `a` with a string directly (like `a['Julian':]`). As the error indicates, you need to use integers for normal slices like that.

The integer you need is the index of `'Julian'` in `a`, which can be obtained by `list.index()`:

```
a = ['Sam','Julian','Edna','Jack','Tressa']

for name in a[a.index('Julian'):]:
    print(name)
```